# How can I print the contents of a file without it looking messy?

Tags: python

I want to print the contents of a file that I have and the code does print the file, but with square brackets, apostrophes and \n after each line. I know that I have to use .strip() and I have tried, but with no success. This is what I have so far:

```
myfile = open("myfile.txt" , "r")
details = myfile.readlines()
print(details)
myfile.close()
```

Comment: What does "with \n after each line"  mean? You see `\n` appear on your screen, or you see each line end with an end-of-line code - a return? (Which should not surprise you that much.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is that you're printing a `list`. The output isn't "messy", it's just what a list looks like when printed as-is.

If you simply want to read the contents of your file as a string instead of a list of strings, don't use `readlines()`, use plain `read()`.

Comment: Thank you. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you already have a list of strings, use

```
print ("".join(details))
```

That will re-join the lines around an empty string. In other words: it concatenates all strings.